# c# how to create a typed dataset from a dataset or a XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have XML file that I can easily load into a dataset.

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(e.FullPath);
```

However, I did like to have a typed dataset instead.
Is there a way to build the typed dataset from the XML or the untyped dataset?

The goal here is to avoid design it because there is a lot of column and it remove the change of making mistake while typing.

Comment: You can generate typed datasets with [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: When saving file use schema : ds.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy to do. Here is a step by step guide.
(You must have visual studio installed of course)

**1. From the XML File, create a XSD File.**

This can be acheived by loading the XML file into a dataset and then writing the schema. The following code take care of this step.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
        ds.ReadXml(e.FullPath);   
        ds.WriteXml(@"C:\test.xsd", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Verify the XSD file is good and doesn't contains junk.

**2. Locate where "xsd.exe" is on your computer.**
In my case, it was here :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

**3. Copy/paste the xsd file into the folder found at step2.**

**4. Run command prompt and change directory to folder found at step2.**

Open a command prompt (Windows+R, type "cmd" and hit enter). Then navigate to the folder found at step2. ("cd enter-your-directory-here")

```
    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
```

Quick tips, you can copy/paste the directory into the prompt using the mouse's right click.

**5. From the command prompt, launch xsd.exe with desired argument.**
Type or paste the following command in the command prompt and press enter.

```
    xsd.exe /d /l:cs test.xsd /eld /n:MyDesiredNameSpace
```

If needed, you can find details about arguments in [msdn documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Given your xsd file was valid, it will output a cs file into the folder. Here is what console output.

[image: Command output]

**6. Include the generated file into your project.**
Copy and paste the generated .cs file into your solution folder and include it to your project.
Using (right-click include existing item)
[image: Include file into project]

**7. Rename the typed dataset with an appropriate name.**
The generated typed dataset is "NewDataset".
Rename it for a more decent name. (use refactor feature)
[image: Rename typed dataset]